# Clap says `cargo` feature flag is required - what does it mean?

Tags: rust, clap

Here is my code in `src/bin/foo.rs`:

```
use clap::command;
pub fn main() {
  let matches = command!("foo")
    .about("Simple util")
    .get_matches();
}
```

I'm getting:

```
error: `cargo` feature flag is required
  --> src/bin/foo.rs:30:19
   |
30 |     let matches = command!("foo")
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
```

Comment: It means (from [ref](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/macro.command.html)):  _Available on crate feature cargo only._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `Cargo.toml` file change your clap dependency to enable the `cargo` feature.

e.g.

```
clap = { version = "3.2.20", features = ["cargo"] }
```

Comment: A complete Rust noob here asking for clarification: if I leave out the features attribute, does it enable all the features? Or are all features disabled by default and must be explicitly enabled like above?

Comment: @AkseliPalén Default features are enabled, whether you have `features` or not. https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#the-default-feature